# How to diff between git tag and branch

Tags: git, tags, branch, diff

While trying to understand the difference between the HEAD of Appium 1.4 branch and tag v1.4.16, I didn't find a way to tell git diff to differentiate between the tag and the branch.

As far as I understand, from git diff's perspective, both the tag and the branch are just aliases to a commit hash, aren't they?

I eventually just created tag 'v1.4' pointing to the branch head (`git checkout 1.4; git tag -a v1.4`) and then I could do `git diff v1.4.16..v1.4` and see the difference I was after.

But this seems a bit strange, is this the only way to achieve what I needed?

Comment: You could have also used the SHA-1 hashes of the commits instead of the tags.  What is your question?

Comment: It's not really clear what the intent of your question is.  It's true that, in Git, either reference simply resolves to a specific commit hash.  Besides the spelling of the full reference name, though—`refs/heads/somebranch` vs `refs/tags/sometag`—the *intent* is different: a branch name is intended to resolve to different commits over time as the branch develops, and a tag name is intended to resolve to the same single commit forever.  When you run `git diff`, though, it just needs to resolve the names *right now*, so there's no need to care about that.

Comment: A tag can point to a commit, but not always. A branch ref points to a commit. A commit points to a tree. In your case, the tag and the branch both point to a commit. So diff between a tag and a branch in your case is to show changes between two commits, or two trees, or the specific blobs in the two trees basically. You could see the chapter of 'Git Internals' in 'Pro Git' to learn about git objects like blob, tree, commit and tag.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I didn't find a way to show the hash that the tag points to. If I did then I suppose I could use that.

Comment: @torek I want to be able to see the diff between a tag and a branch head. I tried using full names but `git diff` though that I'm referring to file names. I now tried again `git diff refs/tags/v1.4.16..refs/heads/1.4` and now it works. I must have had a typo in my previous attempt.

Comment: @ElpieKay: it's true that a tag can point to anything (I've done it just to try it out—tags and annotated tags can point to any object).  However, in general a tag *should* resolve to a commit ID here.  Git generally won't let you set a branch name to point to something other than a commit (I've tried that too, just as a sort of torture-test).

Comment: @AmosShapira: `git rev-parse` will turn any valid identifier into a Git hash.  The identifier can require a specific kind of object (e.g., `x^{tree}` turns `x` into a tree object, unwrapping tags and commits if needed, or else fails if `x` cannot resolve to a tree).  In general you do not need to be this fancy though: just put in the name (`x` in this example) and Git generally does the right thing.

Comment: I was able to get what I wanted using `git rev-parse` as @torek suggested: `git diff $(git rev parse v1.4.16)..$(git rev-parse origin/1.4)`

Comment: @AmosShapira: you *can* do that, but as I noted, you do not *have to* do that.  Just use the name!  Git will call `git rev-parse` for you.  You mainly need to use `git rev-parse` when writing your own scripts and you want to check things early.  For instance you might check that an argument resolves to a tree object, before doing something that takes a long time, so that errors happen early instead of later.

Comment: Thanks @torek. I found that a little later. See my other comments below.

Answer (score 37):

Thanks everyone for the leading suggestions. The issue seems to be that I didn't have a local branch `1.4`. I could achieve what I wanted (i.e. diff between the tag and the branch head on the original Git repo) in a couple of ways:

1. Switch to it (with `git checkout 1.4`), then I could do `git diff v1.4.16`
2. Refer to it on the remote: `git diff v1.4.16..origin/1.4`

Both achieved what I wanted.

Comment: git diff 1.7 --- ambiguous argument '1.7': unknown revision or path not in the working tree. 1.7 is a tag.